# How can I write pl/sql oracle function/procedure to add some data in table?

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I need to write a function/procedure to retrieve return_date of book from two tables. In first table I have book_id and in second member_id. I filled third table loan_evidence with data from first 2 tables and SYSDATE for date_of_loan. Now I need to combine this 3 parameters to get return_date in DATE when the book was returned

Input parameters: book_id,member_id,date_of_loan

Output parameters: return_date

So, if 30 days have not passed from borrowing the book then write into the table loan_evidence when the book is returned, and if it is then raise error that the book is not returned.

How can I properly write this function/procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures and functions are nothing more than SQL statements along with procedural code packaged into a unit that is stored in the database.

In your case, you want to return a single value (the return date) so you probably want to create it as a function.

Next, determine what data you need to work with and write a query to get exactly what you need.  You can develop/test the query outside of the function (using the Developer query window) until you get it the way you want.

Next, determine what procedural logic you will need to process this data.  This can include using local variables, conditional statements, etc.

Finally, perform any database inserts/updates and return the value.

If you are completely new to PL/SQL you may want to start here

http://plsql-tutorial.com/